# Ionic 3 disable scroll bounce effect on iOS

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

So I've been maintaining this app for quite some time. It works on Android just how I want it, because Android doesn't add the stupid bounce effect without your permission. I still want content to scroll, just without the bounce effect because it totally breaks my view when it does the bounce effect on iOS.

A year or two ago when I started this app I managed to get rid of the scroll bouncing effect using this in my config.xml:

```
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```

But that doesn't seem to be working anymore. I haven't touched this project for the last few months so I'm not sure what has changed in Ionic since then. Are there any other ways to disable content bounce?

Edit: I've already tried the `has-bouncing="false"` and `no-bounce` properties on my `ion-content`, which don't do anything.

Comment: what was the fix you used in the end ? I really need a solution for this, that does not kill the smooth scrolling

Answer (score 3):

Well, I did find a solution but it doesn't only stop the bounce, it also disables smooth scrolling. At this point I don't even care, I'm just glad it's working now.

```
.ios {
  .scroll-content {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, did the trick for me, the only solution that worked with ionic 3.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
<ion-content [scrollY]="false" [scrollX]="false">/<ion-content>
```

Change it according to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a no-bounce tag on your ion-content like so:

`<ion-content no-bounce></ion-content`

Comment: Sorry, the no-bounce works depending on the size of the container.

I looked into your issue a little more and came up with this:

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/11584#issuecomment-359813836

It seems to be that the bounce effect is unavoidable in Ionic 2 and 3.

Comment: That's unfortunate, thanks for the info though. I found a solution that fixes it enough.

Comment: @ChrisHansen please share your solution for others.

Answer (score 1):

I know for iOS devices  has different scrolling behaviour , and whatever you add in ionic it wont works , So but that need to do something else.

Here is my library fo removing bouncing effects on iOS.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/disable-ios-scrolling